# LDAP SearchResultCollection to Dictionary?

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary, directorysearcher

I was given an interface to implement, which has a method SearchUser(string filter). In than method I need to search an LDAP server and get users by given filter. Right now, I am doing it with a foreach loop. Is there a more elegant way to do this using LINQ ?

```
public List<Dictionary<string, object>> SearchUser2(string filter)
{
Dictionary<string, object> _SearchUser = null;
List<Dictionary<string, object>> _SearchList = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();
DirectoryEntry domainEntry = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://MyDomain");
DirectorySearcher searcher = new DirectorySearcher(domainEntry);
searcher.Filter = string.Format("(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(mail={0}*))", filter);
DirectoryEntry entry;
SearchResultCollection searchResult = searcher.FindAll();
foreach (SearchResult sr in searchResult)
{
    entry = sr.GetDirectoryEntry();

    if (entry != null)
    {
        _SearchUser.Add("Mail", entry.Properties["Mail"].Value);
        .....
        _SearchList.Add(_SearchUser);
    }
}
return _SearchList;
}
```